# MKNetworkKit file upload not working in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, file-upload, upload, amazon-web-services

I am using [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) perfectly fine for all of my server requests. However, when trying to upload an image file, it is failing with this error:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x1010cb20 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/net.myapp.upload, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/net.myapp.upload, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0x1010ca60 "The network connection was lost."}

Sometimes the error code is 405. I have all of the amazon credentials needed to upload, and running a cURL in the terminal with the same outgoing data the app has yields a proper return. The method I use for this request is here:

```
 - (MKNetworkOperation*)uploadMediaFromFile:(NSString*)file urlCommand:(NSString*)url    
 postField:(NSString*)field authDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)authDict onCompletion:(   
 MediaUploadBlock)completionBlock onError:(MKNKErrorBlock)errorBlock  {

    MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithURLString:url params:authDict                           
     httpMethod:@"POST"];

    [op addFile:file forKey:field];

    // setFreezable uploads your images after connection is restored!
    [op setFreezable:YES];

    [op onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation* completedOperation) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[completedOperation responseString]);
        NSDictionary *jsonString = [completedOperation responseJSON];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
        completionBlock(jsonString);
    }
     onError:^(NSError* error) {
         errorBlock(error);
     }];

    [self enqueueOperation:op forceReload:YES];

    return op;
 }
```

It's a fairly basic request that works from terminal and works from the browser using the same parameters provided here. I can't figure out why this isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"The network connection is lost" means your Wifi connection is poor, intermittent.